# ChannelGroup not working as intended in Netty 4.1.6

Tags: java, netty

I have a `ChannelGroup` containing 4 clients that have logged in one by one and have been added to the group as they log in through the Netty method `handlerAdded`.

```
static ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE); 

@Override
public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    channels.add(ctx.channel());
    assignGroup(ctx.channel());
}
```

I later save my `ChannelGroup` in an object named `GameMaster` and initialize a game loop that gives each client a chance to play its turn:

```
    static ChannelGroup channels; // contains the actual channels, saved in contructor

    public void bettingPhase(boolean isOk) {
    int i = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for (Channel chan : channels) { // Should start on the first client that logged in
        Server.MyMessage.Builder message = Server.MyMessage.newBuilder();
        message.setKeyword("304");
        message.setValue("Please input a contract:");
        chan.writeAndFlush(message); // PROBLEM HERE
        while (isOk == false) { // Loop to check the playing client's input
            Server.MyMessage.Builder message2 = Server.MyMessage.newBuilder();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if (playerAnswer.getKeyword().equals("CONTRACT")) {
                    System.out.println("Player has inputed contract.");
                    i++;
                    message2.setKeyword("310");
                    chan.writeAndFlush(message); // Tells the current client his turn is over
                    System.out.println("End of turn for player.");
                    for (Channel channel : channels) { // Loop to tell the next client it's his turn
                        if (y == i) {
                            message2.setKeyword("309");
                            channel.writeAndFlush(message);
                            System.out.println("Start of turn for player.");
                        }
                        y++;
                    }
                    isOk = true;
                    playerAnswer.clearKeyword();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        isOk = false;
    }
}
```

Please excuse this big chunk of code.

But for some reason my sentence `"304 Please input a contract:"` sent via `chan.writeAndFlush(message);` is sent to another client (and not the first one as it should through the loop) !

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "first one"?  ChannelGroup is a Set and it makes no guarantee to maintain insertion order when being iterated.

Comment: I did not know that, I have now saved them in a `Channel[]` in order to access them as I wish.